# How to select points from matrix with given probability?

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have a `numpy.ndarray` `points` representing a set of coordinate points:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]]
```

I want to get a subset of this points `some_points` where each point is independently taken with probability `prob`. How can I do this using only `numpy`?

P.S. For instance, if `prob=0.5` `some_points` will contain about a half of original points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = points.size
some_points = points[np.random.rand(n * n) < p]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example create a vector with n samples from the uniform distribution, with n being the number of points and compare those with your desired probability. For all samples smaller than the probability you take the corresponding point. In code

```py
import numpy as np
prob = 0.5
some_points = points[np.random.rand(points.shape[0]) < prob, :]
```